# (Python) randint if/else error

Tags: python

I am running Python 3.6.4 and having trouble with the randint function. In trying to create a simple piece of code to create a random number and for each number, print a different response.
My current code reads as follows:

```
from random import *

test = randint(0, 3)
if test == 0:
        print("Zero")
        if test == 1:
            print("Number One")
            if test == 2:
                print("Number Two")
                if test == 3:
                    print("Number Three")
```

The only problem is, It will only print something if the randint creates the number zero. So it has a one in 4 chance of printing "Zero", the rest print nothing.

I'm obviously being an idiot and missing something really simple but...

Comment: Check your indentation.  Each `if` should be at the same level, not nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from random import *

test = randint(0, 3)
if test == 0:
        print("Zero")
elif test == 1:
          print("Number One")
elif test == 2:
          print("Number Two")
elif test == 3:
          print("Number Three")
```

All of your if statements were nested, so if the number wasn't 0 they would never be reached!

Also, while it's not necessary, you can change the subsequent `if` statements to `elif` statements. Your code will check each of your `if` statements, even if you meet the first condition. Using `elif` will make the code stop checking after/if it meets any of the conditions!

Answer (score 0):

Yuu want to remove those extra indents and have ALL the if statements at the same indentation level.  It would also be nice to use "elif" rather than if.

```
if test == 0:
    print(0)
elif test == 2:
    print(2)
......
......
else:
    print("junk")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if 0 isnt drawn, none of the rest of the code will run; including the other checks. Think about it:

```
test = randint(0, 3)
#Everything under this, including the other checks
#  will only run if test == 0. 
if test == 0:
    print("Zero") 

    if test == 1:
        print("Number One")
```

You need to use an `elif`:

```
if test == 0:
    print("Zero") 

elif test == 1: # This is checked if the first check fails
    print("Number One")
```